# Is there a missing file equivalent of erroronmissingdir in Ant?

Tags: ant, fileset

We have a file set in our Ant build which looks like this:

```
<fileset dir="somewhere/lib" includesfile="third-party-jars.txt"/>
```

Every jar is then spelled out in full in the text file. (The reason we have it in a separate text file is actually nothing to do with build file brevity, but rather so that it's easier to inspect the list from an integration test we have which checks that all third-party jar file licences are documented.)

Someone made a commit which prevented a file going into the build. Ant didn't pick up the missing file at all - the build proceeded. It seems bad that even though the file names are spelled out in full, a file being missing isn't detected... so I'm trying to solve that now.

There is an attribute for `erroronmissingdir`, but adding it doesn't help (the `dir` isn't missing.) Is there a way to get an error on missing files in a fileset? Ideally a compact way... because we have more than one of these filesets and duplicating code doesn't sound appealing.

Other people have asked simpler variants of this where they wanted to check a single file. To check a single file, you use the `available` task. It seems like `available` only supports one resource though.

I took a shot at restricting the resource collection to try and find available vs. unavailable resources.

```
<restrict id="temp.available"><resources refid="@{ref-name}"/></restrict>
<difference id="temp.unavailable">
  <resources refid="@{ref-name}"/>
  <resources refid="temp.available"/>
</difference>
<fail message="Missing stuff">
  <condition>
    <resourcecount refid="temp.unavailable" when="greater" count="0"/>
  </condition>
</fail>
```

This doesn't work, seemingly because the resource collection is already missing the items which don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is impossible to get with the native `fileset` support. `fileset` works as a scanner: it is based on a particular directory, and includes all files according to the inclusion/exclusion patterns you provide. Even `erroronmissingdir` wasn't a part of `fileset` until Ant 1.7 or so.

Your best bet is to write a macro around the `available` task, passing a resource collection to the macro and use a `for` loop (from Ant-Contrib) to test the availability of each file.

Comment: Hmm, no matter what I do with <available>, it claims the resource isn't available even for resources which clearly are. :/ I'm guessing it has something to do with my use of filesets based at a non-root directory or possibly to do with using mapped resources.

Comment: This is very strange. Try running Ant using the `-d` switch.